# Using the Log Analytics REST API with MSAL instead of ADAL

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, azure-log-analytics

So this works:

```
$LATokenRequestBody = @{
    tenant        = $myVarTenantId
    client_id     = $myVarClientId
    client_secret = $myVarClientSecret
    resource      = "https://api.loganalytics.io"  
    grant_type    = "client_credentials"
    }
$LATokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $ADALTokenEndpoint -Body $LATokenRequestBody
$LARequestHeaderParameters = @{'Authorization'="$($LATokenResponse.token_type) $($LATokenResponse.access_token)"}
$LAQueryBody = @{query = $myVarLAQuery} | ConvertTo-Json
$LAResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -UseBasicParsing -Headers $LARequestHeaderParameters -Uri $LAEndpoint -Method Post -Body $LAQueryBody -ContentType "application/json"
```

This does not:

```
$LATokenRequestBody = @{
    tenant        = $myVarTenantId
    client_id     = $myVarClientId
    client_secret = $myVarClientSecret
    scope         = "https://westus2.api.loganalytics.io/Data.Read"
    grant_type    = "client_credentials"
    }
$LATokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $MSALTokenEndpoint -Body $LATokenRequestBody
$LARequestHeaderParameters = @{'Authorization'="$($LATokenResponse.token_type) $($LATokenResponse.access_token)"}
$LAQueryBody = @{query = $myVarLAQuery} | ConvertTo-Json
$LAResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -UseBasicParsing -Headers $LARequestHeaderParameters -Uri $LAEndpoint -Method Post -Body $LAQueryBody -ContentType "application/json"
```

Where:

```
$ADALTokenEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$myVarTenantId/oauth2/token" # required for Log Analytics API
$MSALTokenEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$myVarTenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"
```

I don't see any mention of MSAL being supported on the Log Analytics API documentation:

https://dev.loganalytics.io/documentation/Authorization/OAuth2

The Log Analytics API won't accept a token from the MSAL endpoint:

[image]

Comment: I don't see anything related to ADAL or MSAL in your example code, all I see are manual created webrequests. (FYI: MSAL and ADAL are the client libraries created by Microsoft to authenticate against their Oauth2 token endpoints, the endpoints aren't called MSAL or ADAL)

Comment: You're obviously right but this is how a lot of people commonly refer to it. If I were to appropriately call it v1 and v2, I'm pretty sure a lot of people wouldn't know what I'm talking about, and to be completely correct I'd have to say v1 and "The Microsoft Identity Platform endpoint", which (to make it clearer ) is also the name for the entire authentication service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `scope = https://api.loganalytics.io/.default` in the `$LATokenRequestBody`, it should work.

Comment: That worked... kinda feeling dumb now , didn't think it would work similarly to the Graph API. Thanks!